# Using .loc in pandas slows down calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe where I want to assign the bottom 1% value to a new column. When I do this calculation with using the ".loc" notification, it takes around 10 seconds for using .loc assignment, where the alternative solution is only 2 seconds.

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000000,1),columns=list('A'))
%time df_temp["q"] = df_temp["A"].quantile(0.01)
%time df_temp.loc[:, "q1_loc"] = df_temp["A"].quantile(0.01)
```

Why is the .loc solution slower? I understand using the .loc solution is safer, but if I want to assign data to all indices in the column, what can go wrong with the direct assignment?

Comment: I get no such differences `In [355]: %time df_temp["q"] = df_temp["A"].quantile(0.01) Wall time: 1.67 s`, `In [356]: %time df_temp.loc[:, "q1_loc"] = df_temp["A"].quantile(0.01) Wall time: 1.92 s`, `In [357]: %time df.assign(q=df_temp["A"].quantile(0.01))
Wall time: 1.28 s`, tested in `pandas 0.22.0, python: 3.5.1., win 7`

Comment: I get a similar difference as the OP, using `pandas 0.21.1`, `python 3.6.3`, `macOS 10.13.3`

Comment: I am using python 2.7.13 and pandas 0.22.0. The solution provided by sacul takes around 5 seconds. Strangely enough, if I rerun the code without reloading the dataframe, the calculation time of the first and second solution are almost equal. (2.53 vs 2.58 seconds) and the assign method is the slowest then with 4.9 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.loc` is searching along the entirety of indices and columns (in this case, only 1 column) in your df along the whole axes, which is time consuming and perhaps redundant, in addition to figuring out the quantiles of `df_temp['A']` (which is negligible as far as calculation time). Your direct assignment method, on the other hand, is just parsing `df_temp['A'].quantile(0.01)`, and assigning `df_temp['q']`. It doesn't need to exhaustively search the indices/columns of your df.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27597343/6671176) for a similar description of the `.loc` method.

As far as safety is concerned, you are not using chained indexing, so you're probably safe (you're not trying to set anything on a *copy* of your data, it's being set directly on the data itself). It's good to be aware of the potential issues with not using `.loc` (see [this post](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/) for a nice overview of `SettingWithCopy` warnings), but I think that you're OK as far as that goes.

If you want to be *more* explicit about your column creation, you could do something along the lines of `df = df.assign(q=df_temp["A"].quantile(0.01))`. It won't really change performance (I don't think), nor the result, but it allows you to see that you're explicitly assigning a new column to your existing dataframe (and thus not setting anything on a copy of said dataframe).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the assign solution still takes more than twice as long as the direct assignment. I guess I'll stick with the direct assignment, although it is a bit annoying to get the warnings that I should .loc instead.